Competing Risks that are not mutually exclusive in Survival Analysis
I have 5 type of events that a subject can experience. However, not all these events are competing with each other: For the events A, B, C, D, E; occurrence of A blocks B from happening. B, D and E preclude each other and occurrence of C blocks all the other events. I want to estimate the cumulative incidence for each event with Aalen-Johansen estimator, but I am not sure how to handle and interpret these competing cases.

What you are describing is a multistate transition model as discussed here.  The vignette does not cover the constraints you mentioned but probably does cover absorbing states.  Multistate models are easier to deal with, and easier to add constraints, when dealing with discrete time, as exemplified here.  The constraints come from how you model previous states.  For example if the previous state is A, the probability that the current state is B would be set to 0.
